# Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined (p5.min.js:4604:988)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to take user input and use it to generate some things. It works when I hardcode the inputs for the generator like this:

```
function setup() {

    createCanvas(1280, 512);

    generator = new Room_map(5, 10, 15);

    generator.draw();
}
```

However, when I try to take user input and generate when the user clicks the 'generate' button, the error in the title shows up.

I followed the guide on p5.js reference (https://p5js.org/examples/dom-input-and-button.html) and this is my code for taking user input:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(1280, 512);

    generator = new Room_map(5, 10, 15);

    input_no_of_rooms = createInput();
    input_no_of_rooms.position(1100, 50);

    input_min_size = createInput();
    input_min_size.position(1100, 90);

    input_max_size = createInput();
    input_max_size.position(1100, 130);

    if (input_no_of_rooms > 0 &&
        input_min_size > 0 &&
        input_max_size > 0)
    {
        generator = new Room_map(
            input_no_of_rooms.value(), 
            input_min_size.value(), 
            input_max_size.value())
    }

    button = createButton('Generate');
    button.position(1100, 155);
    button.mousePressed(generator.draw());

    background(200);

    push();
    fill(0);
    text("Number of rooms: ", 1095, 40);
    text("Min room size: ", 1095, 80);
    text("Max room size: ", 1095, 120);
    pop();
}
```

I have no draw function in my code.

Comment: What's the point of getting the input in `setup`? `setup` ist just executed once at the beginning. You need to get the input in `draw`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Is this the issue? I followed the example in the link I attached and it worked fine for multiple different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is the issue:

```
button.mousePressed(generator.draw());
```

This will invoke `generator.draw()` once and register whatever it returns as the `mousePressed` handler. Since you did not include the code for `Room_map` I can only speculate what `draw()` does, but I'm guessing it does not return a function object, and probably returns `undefined`. As a result whenever the mouse is pressed there will be an error because you cannot invoke `undefined` as a function. What you probably meant to do is use an anonymous function:

```
button.mousePressed(() => generator.draw());
```